# Volunteers for Salesforce Visualforce page Field Set not usable in Community

Tags: visualforce, community-cloud

The Volunteers for Salesforce visualforce page VolunteersReportHours has been exposed to a community using a web tab. However, I can't seem to make the field set VolunteersReportHoursFS work. The labels for First Name, Last Name and Email all appear but there is no data shown and no input field. 
When previewing the page I can see and input data into the fields. The visualforce page does not have the communities check box ticked, and I cannot tick it (managed package). Is it simply this? or is there some field level security or permission I need to alter?
Please can you help?

Comment: I think it's field level security or manage package license issue...

Comment: That's what I was thinking... trouble is I can't see where the fields are pulled from to make them visible! Also with communities I don't want to expose something that shouldn't be.

Comment: You can turn on debug log....you would be able to see on which object and fields query is being made

Comment: Thank you Ayub! I think I have the rub: it's a cross between community licence type, OWD requirements of V4S and managed package visualforce pages.

Comment: Good to hear that...you got the issue...